# Integral of a non-negative continuous function on a closed bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have recently been trying some questions on improper integral and I saw this written over somewhere.

$f$ is a continuous function from [$0,1$] to $\Bbb{R}$ and $f$(t) $\geq$ $0$

We define $g$(x) = $\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$

Then m $\le$ $g$(x) $\le$ M?

where M is $\sup_{f}$[$0,1$] and m is $\inf_{f}$[$0,1$]

Is this true?

The question actually was to show that $g$ is bounded.I think I can prove that value of $g$ lies between $0$ and M.But I am unable to show that it lies between m and M.

Help,please

Comment: It is not true. Take $f(x) = 1$, then $\inf_{[0,1]}(f) = 1$, but $g(0) = 0  < \inf_{[0,1]}(f) = 1$. However you should be able to show $x\inf_{[0,1]}(f) \leq g(x)$.

Comment: What is true is that $mx\le g(x)\le Mx$ for $x\in[0,1]$. (Obviously $m\le g(x)$ can't be right, because $g(0)=0$.)

Comment: @Dayton shown that..thanks for the clarification

Comment: @TonyK..thanks for the clarification